# Creating a list of variable length arrays in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, cell-array

I would like to process a list of images with `regionprops` and save the result into an array or a list of some kind.

My problem is that `regionprops` returns a variable size struct. It looks like this in my case:

```
stats = regionprops(L,'Centroid');

2x1 struct array with fields:
    Centroid
```

The size of the struct depends from image to image.

How can I create an object which holds all my **structs**? Do I need to use **cell arrays**?

I tried the following:

```
mycell = struct2cell(stats);
centers(i,:) = mycell;
```

But it only works as long as my cell arrays have the same size. It is not the case here, as the number of detected objects **change from frame to frame**.

**How can I store variable length structs or cell arrays in a container?**

**What should I use, structs of cell arrays?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put each struct array `stats` inside a cell of its own. For example:

```
>> stats1(3).test = 1

stats1 = 

1x3 struct array with fields:
    test

>> stats2(2).test = 1

stats2 = 

1x2 struct array with fields:
    test

>> [{stats1} {stats2}]

ans = 

    [1x3 struct]    [1x2 struct]
```

Comment: But how can I do [{stats1} {stats2}] by an algorithm, in a loop? I would like to do something like `for i = 1:size(images) .... allstats{i} = stats` or something similar?

Comment: You got it! Good luck with the project!